# bit shifting in float stored in 1byte array

Tags: c, floating-point, bit-shift

I have array of 1 byte which stores the float value. I am trying to extract it using following way. I am not sure if it is right or wrong.

```
t32 = (float32)((pt[BMW_DATASTARTPOS_NO_QUAL])
      + (float32)(pt[BMW_DATASTARTPOS_NO_QUAL + 1] << 8)
      + (float32)(pt[BMW_DATASTARTPOS_NO_QUAL + 2] << 16)
      + (float32)(pt[BMW_DATASTARTPOS_NO_QUAL + 3] << 24));
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but that is definitely not right.

Comment: Bit shifting floats!! never!.

Comment: Unless i am misreading the (), it is actually casting the result of the shift to float, not shifting the float itself. Still wrong though

Comment: you should have `pt[i]` as byte, no cast, and or (`|`) each "piece" in an integer data as large as float32 (so, a 32 bit integer will suffice). Then, you can interpret the value as float32, with something like `(float32*)&int_data` (and the deferencing it to get the float). Thus, `int_data = pt[a] | (pt[a+1]<<8) | ...`; pt[a] should be a byte (unsigned octet, I mean) and `int_data` unsigned too, to avoid problems with sign extension or alike. Provided that I've interpreted correctly what you're trying to achieve - yet you must be sure of the correct byte ordering

Comment: Float te, t32;  unsigned char * pt; pt = &te;

Answer (score 0):

A simple "by value" cast of a `float` cannot convert it to/from its binary representation, it will always convert its numeric value instead.

You need to "union-cast" the `float32`, or write it through an `int32` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
memcpy(&t32, &pt[BMW_DATASTARTPOS_NO_QUAL], 4) ;
```

or

```
t32 = *(float*)&pt[BMW_DATASTARTPOS_NO_QUAL] ;
```

Small illustration:

```
float f = 1.5f ;
BYTE b[4] ;
memcpy(b, &f, 4) ;

float l ;
memcpy(&l, &b[0], 4) ;
// now l contains also 1.5f

float k ;
k = *(float*)&b[0] ;
// now k contains also 1.5f
```

Comment: how we have to do if we have to copy the float to a unit8 array[7] starting from array[2].

Comment: @user3285192: please elaborate your question, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I have a uint8 arr[8]; Float32 F32 . I want to copy the Float32 in to array buffer.  where first 2 element/byte shall be empty  . the float32 value shall appear in arr[2-5].